# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: tickets_ticket_notes.ticket_id

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am getting this error on when I try to create a note or comment section to a post. I am trying to make kind of a ticketing system and if I remove the section where it looks for existing comments/notes it works fine. I feel as if  I am missing a connection to the tickets/post from the notes/comments.
I have a the notes linked to the tickets by a foreign key in my models.  not sure what else I am missing.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: tickets_ticket_notes.ticket_id
```

Models.py

```
class Tickets(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Assigned', "Assigned"),
        ('Traveling', "Travelling"),
        ('Completed', "Completed"),
        ('On Hol', "On Hold"),
    )
    assigned_tech = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,)
    ticket_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    SM_number = models.CharField(max_length=14, default="service manager number")
    slug = models.SlugField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length= 10, choices=STATUS, default='Assigned')
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(datetime.date.today())
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, default="Must Change")
    asset_tag = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=30, default='enter address')
    city_state = models.CharField(max_length=14, default='enter city/state')
    description = models.TextField(default='enter ticket description')


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('ticket_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticket_number


class Ticket_Notes(models.Model):
    TYPE = (
        (0, "On Site"),
        (1, "Travelling"),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Tickets, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='notes')
    note =models.TextField(blank=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    entry_type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE, default=0)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.note, self.user)
```

views.py

```
def ticket_details(request, slug=None):
    ticket = get_object_or_404(Tickets, slug=slug)
    notes = ticket.notes.order_by('created_on')
    new_note = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        note_form = NoteForm(data=request.POST)
        tech = note_form.save(commit=False)
        tech.user = request.user
        tech.save()
        if note_form.is_valid():
            note_form = note_form.save(commit=False)
            note_form.ticket = ticket
            note_form.save()
    else:
        note_form = NoteForm()
    return render(request, "ticket_detail.html", {'ticket':ticket, 'notes':notes,
                                                  'new_note':new_note,'note_form':note_form})
```

I've ran make migration and migrate as well as migrate --run-syncdb. I cannot figure out where this issue is but pretty sure it is in my models.

Comment: I think you added `ticket` to `Ticket_Notes` after creating `Ticket_Notes` table  and didn't    use `python manage.py makemigrations`  and `python manage.py migrate` after adding this new field. First of all make sure that you did it correctly and check that your database table has this column.

Comment: I moved this app to a fresh database and that seemed to resolve the problem. Guess it was an issue with the database not the code. Probably from deleting a migration file.